# Is iPad Pro with Pencil the best route to take for drawing custom icons?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, drawing, drawing-tablet

I'm looking to make the investment in a drawing tablet. I've looked into Intuos, but have never played with it. I played with the ipad pro and pencil and really loved it. What are some of your experiences with either product?

Comment: Not all people have a workflow that benefits form tablet input. For me this is especially true when creating icons. So if you are alleeady doing icons by drawing on paper then digitizing them then yes this may benefit you.

Comment: Good points @joojaa

Comment: I've done a handful of paper drawn items, but in the recent months, I've been doing more of it, so that's why I want to explore tablet options, to take one less step out of the process

Answer (score 1):

Only you can really say what is best for you.  Best is highly subjective.

You can't run Adobe Illustrator on iOS devices.  It only works on Macs and Windows.  There's the Illustrator Draw app for iOS and Android tablets, but it's not the same thing as Adobe Illustrator. However it might be fine for your purposes.

There are Wacom Cintiques which run a full Windows operating system which could run Adobe's Creative Cloud products, including Illustrator, Photoshop, etc.

Wacom Intuous tablets have no integrated display, they are only input devices.